# Jackrabbit unclosed session detected on AccessDeniedException but session is null

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm working with Jackrabbit 2.13.1.

Why AccessDeniedException causes session leak?

```
        try {
            session = repository.login(creds); //here are creds for user without permissions, just for testing
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (session != null) {
                session.logout();
            }
            Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(t, javax.jcr.RepositoryException.class);
            throw Throwables.propagate(t);
        }
```

This throws, as expected, AccessDeniedException:

```
Caused by: javax.jcr.LoginException: Workspace access denied
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:1529)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:144)
    at ttt.createSession(RepositoryManager.java:132)
    ... 51 common frames omitted

Caused by: javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: Not allowed to access Workspace default
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager.init(DefaultAccessManager.java:159)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager.getAccessManager(DefaultSecurityManager.java:280)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.createAccessManager(SessionImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl.<init>(XASessionImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createSessionInstance(RepositoryImpl.java:1613)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createSession(RepositoryImpl.java:956)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:1501)
```

session is null, so I'm unable to call logout on it. But unclosed session detected exception is thrown:

```
WARN  o.a.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl - Unclosed session detected. The session was opened here: 
java.lang.Exception: Stack Trace
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl.<init>(XASessionImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createSessionInstance(RepositoryImpl.java:1613)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createSession(RepositoryImpl.java:956)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:1501)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:144)
    at ttt.createSession(RepositoryManager.java:132)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch, this sounds **clearly as a bug** that still exists in `2.13.3` and that occurs in case an exception is thrown in the constructor of `SessionImpl`, the session is then partially created but it is still considered as alive and a live session that is about to be GCed is considered as a session leak by the current code this is why you get this warning.

I've just created a ticket for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-4033